# Where is asset_host rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What happened to asset_host in rails 3?
Earlier I can put following code into development.rb and get all assets not present on development:

```
ActionController::Base.asset_host = proc do |source, request|
  unless File.exist?(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'public', source.sub(/\?\d+$/, '')))
    'http://example.com'
  end
end
```

But in rails 3 there is no such method and google does not help me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The asset_host config information goes into you environment files, which have changed format slightly:

```
// environments/production.rb
Infinity::Application.configure do

  config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

end
```

I'm not sure this will let you override in the same way as your code, though.

Comment: Finally, I found info going through rails source. It allows assigning proc as it earlier version.